# Spring HibernateTemplate - Autowiring

Tags: hibernate, spring

Instead of autowiring SessionFactory and creating HibernateTemplate, Is it Ok to autowire HibernateTemplate?

```
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
...
}
```

instead of above code, is it fine to have like given below?

```
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {

@Autowired private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

...
}
```

and configure HibernateTemplate in the XML.

What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this but if you're using Hibernate 3.0.1 , you could avoid hibernate template .The following is from the Hibernate template Api [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html)

```
NOTE: As of Hibernate 3.0.1, transactional Hibernate access code can also be coded in 
plain Hibernate style. Hence, for newly started projects, consider adopting the standard
Hibernate3 style of coding data access objects instead, based on 
SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
```

Also as per the jboss support quoted [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?25251-hibernateTemplate-and-hibernate3)

```
If you plan to use the Spring Hibernate template, then don't.
The Spring template were useful with Hibernate 2.x because of some mistakes we made   
the main one beeing checked exceptions. This is no longer the case for Hibernate 3.x. 
If you remove this exception wrapping necessity, Spring template are lust an overhead 
on top of the Hibernate API (hiding you the richness of the Hibernate API is some 
cases).
```

One of the major changes in Hibernate 3 was a moved from checked to unchecked exceptions . Read the article [here](http://www.kimchy.org/hibernate_vs_spring_hibernate_template/) for a good info on this and one more [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's fine. It's no better or worse than the first approach, it's just different.

Pick whichever one you feel improves your code readability, that's the only real difference, and it's subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and not surprisingly, Spring already provides a simple mechanism for this provided your DAO's extend from [HibernateDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.html). You will then have access to the template using `getHibernateTemplate()`. The only disadvantage I can think of is that your DAO is coupled with Spring specific classes but coupling with well tested libraries is OK. Also, you already have direct reference to `HibernateTemplate` anyway.